# Transform random draws from a bivariate normal into the unit square in Matlab

Tags: matlab, normalization, normal-distribution

I have an `nx2` matrix `r` in Matlab reporting `n` draws from a bivariate normal distribution

```
n=1000;
m1=0.3;
m2=-m1;
v1=0.2;
n=10000;
v2=2;
rho=0.5;

mu = [m1, m2];
sigma = [v1,rho*sqrt(v1)*sqrt(v2);rho*sqrt(v1)*sqrt(v2),v2];
r = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,n);
```

I want to normalise these draws to the unit square `[0,1]^2`

---

**First option**

```
rmax1=max(r(:,1));
rmin1=min(r(:,1));
rmax2=max(r(:,2));
rmin2=min(r(:,2));
rnew=zeros(n,2);
for i=1:n
    rnew(i,1)=(r(i,1)-rmin1)/(rmax1-rmin1);
    rnew(i,2)=(r(i,2)-rmin2)/(rmax2-rmin2); 
end
```

---

**Second option**

`rmin1`, `rmax1`, `rmin2`, `rmax2` may be quite variable due to the sampling process. An alternative is applying the 68–95–99.7 rule ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)) and I am asking for some help on how to generalise it to a bivariate normal (**in particular Step 1 below**). Here's my idea

```
%Step 1: transform the draws in r into draws from a bivariate normal 
%with variance-covariance matrix equal to the 2x2 identity matrix 
%and mean equal to mu
%How?
%Let t be the transformed vector

%Step 2: apply the 68–95–99.7 rule to each column of t
tmax1=mu(1)+3*1;
tmin1=mu(1)-3*1;
tmax2=mu(2)+3*1;
tmin2=mu(2)-3*1;
tnew=zeros(n,2);
for i=1:n
    tnew(i,1)=(t(i,1)-tmin1)/(tmax1-tmin1);
    tnew(i,2)=(t(i,1)-tmin2)/(tmax2-tmin2);
 end
%Step 3: discard potential values (very few) outside [0,1]
```

Comment: Applying linear transformation to normal variable leaves it a normal variable (with different parameters). To transform normal to uniform, the transformation must be non linear

Comment: I don't need to get a uniform.

Comment: So your title is somewhat confusing - "draws from the unit square" can be easily interpreted as uniform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the x and y coordinates of the random vector are correlated, so it's not just a transformation in x and in y independently. You first need to rotate your samples so that x and y become uncorrelated (then the covariance matrix will be diagonal. You don't need it to be the identity, since anywya you normalize later). Then you can apply the transformation you call "2nd option" to the new x and y independently. Shortly, you need to diagonalize the covariance matrix.

As a side note, your code adds/subtracts 3 times 1, instead of 3 times the standard deviation. Also, you can avoid the for loop, using (e.g) Matlab's `bsxfun` which applies an operation between matrix and vector:

```
t = bsxfun(@minus,r,mean(r,1)); % center the data
[v, d] = eig(sigma);            % find the directions for projection
t = t * v;                      % the projected data is uncorrelated  
sigma_new = sqrt(diag(d));      % that's the std in the new coordinates
% now transform each coordinate independently
tmax1 = 3*sigma_new(1);
tmin1 = -3*sigma_new(1);
tmax2 = 3*sigma_new(2);
tmin2 = -3*sigma_new(2);
tnew = bsxfun(@minus, t, [tmin1, tmin2]);
tnew = bsxfun(@rdivide, tnew, [tmax1-tmin1, tmax2-tmin2]);
```

You still need to discard the few samples which are out of `[0,1]`, as you wrote.

Comment: Thank you. Is this similar to a Choleski decomposition of the variance covariance matrix?

Comment: No. These are two different things.

Comment: Just to understand better your answer: what would be wrong or different in doing this 
`U=chol(sigma); 
L=U'; 
Z1=inv(L)*(r(:,1)-mu(1));
Z2=inv(L)*(r(:,2)-mu(2));
Z=[Z1 Z2]; 
Zmax1=mu(1)+3*1;
Zmin1=mu(1)-3*1;
Zmax2=mu(2)+3*1;
Zmin2=mu(2)-3*1;
Znew=zeros(n,2);
for i=1:n
    Znew(i,1)=(Z(i,1)-Zmin1)/(Zmax1-Zmin1);
    Znew(i,2)=(Z(i,1)-Zmin2)/(Zmax2-Zmin2);
end`

Comment: Sorry, above I am subtracting the mean twice, it should be `Zmax1=3*1; Zmin1=-3*1; Zmax2=3*1; Zmin2=-3*1; `

Comment: Also, regarding your answer. I can see that it is related to the eigen decomposition. `sigma=v*d*transpose(v)`. Why I multiply `t` by `v` and not by `inv(v)`?

Comment: you want to project your vectors along the columns of v, and since your data is the rows of t, t*v gives you exactly the projections you need. Also, sigma is symmetric so v is orthogonal, that is inv(v)=transpose(v)